# Linq query from a string

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq, linq-expressions

I'm trying to build a web application that allows to make any basic linq query (any query that shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) on a list with data- iam getting a linq query as a string from the client and want to run it in my server. But I didn't found any easy way to make it.. Is there any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert LINQ query to string, send to remote server to parse into an expression using Roslyn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647983/convert-linq-query-to-string-send-to-remote-server-to-parse-into-an-expression)

Comment: Possible dublicate [How to create LINQ Query from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139467/how-to-create-linq-query-from-string)

Comment: Try looking into OData - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api